# How to register a menu based on a ACF condition

Tags: functions, menus

I am trying to register a Wordpress menu, depending on a ACF field condition.

```
$logo = get_field('logo','options');

if ($logo) {

register_nav_menus(array(
'brand_centered_left' => __('Brand Centered Navigation (Left)', 'roots')
));  

}
```

However, if I test this code, the navigation does not show. It seems like ACF and functions.php does not work well together, but im not sure.

I am adding this code in my nav.php (which is an include in my functions.php file).I am using Wordpress + ACF 5.0 and Wordpress Roots theme.

Any ideas?

Edit

---

So I tried calling the field directly:

```
if (get_field('logo','options')) {
  register_nav_menus(array(
  'brand_centered_left' => __('Brand Centered Navigation (Left)', 'roots')
  ));  
}
```

and it works! But then again if I try just using $logo it won't work.

Weird!

Comment: Did you test to make sure it was ACF causing the problems? eg. `echo` something instead of registering a menu? I made a test case and ACF worked fine exactly how you have it above.

Comment: Hi @corygibbons. I did try to register a sidebar (just to test) and the sidebar does not show either. Care to elaborate how you did the test please?

Comment: Just something simple like this: https://gist.github.com/corygibbons/5a62344815afbf738f64

Also double check you have the field name correct.

Comment: Hi @corygibbons, thanks for your help. Please check the updated question. I am getting there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that I was adding the variable outside the function. After some cleanup, code looks like this and it works!

```
function roots_setup() {

// Variables

$header_type = get_field('header_type','options');

if (($header_type)=='brand-centered') {

register_nav_menus(array(
'brand_centered_left' => __('Brand Centered Navigation (Left)', 'roots')
));  

register_nav_menus(array(
'brand_centered_right' => __('Brand Centered Navigation (Right)', 'roots')
));  

} else {

register_nav_menus(array(
'primary_navigation' => __('Primary Navigation', 'roots')
));

}
```